# Trigger "mount as disk drive" (aka "USB Mass Storage" mode) from PC

Tags: adb, htc-droid-incredible, usb-connection-mode

I've got an HTC Incredible that I sync to my Linux box.  I'd like the Linux box to automatically detect that the phone is attached (I can do that via `adb wait-for-device`), and then automatically put the device in "disk drive mode" (I've no idea how to do this part), and then mount the phone as storage, and run my sync script (I've got this covered), and then unmount the phone and return it to "charge only" mode.

I can manually put the device in "disk drive mode" by pulling down the shade and changing the "USB connection type", but I'm not sure how to trigger this remotely from the PC.  Ideally, some `adb` command would be great, but I'm open to installing an app, or other hacks (the Linux box can usually reach the phone via WiFi ...)

"Disk drive mode" is also known as "USB Mass Storage" (UMS) mode.

In newer (ICS and later), UMS support is being deprecated for MTP (slightly different USB-based transfer protocol).

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 1):

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.automount) is designed to mount your phone as soon as it is plugged in. It seems to do your missing step.

<strike>Alternatively, this command (found from [this forum](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f41/can-i-turn-on-usb-mass-storage-through-the-recovery-console-19999/#post211352)) can be run on the phone (ex. adb shell) to turn on disk mode.</strike>

`echo /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /sys/devices/platform/usb_mass_storage/lun0/file` 
Edit: This only appears to work in recovery.

[image: App - Auto Mount Your SD Card]

Auto Mount App

Comment: Good to know this is possible, but having the phone go into "disk drive mode" every time the phone is plugged in won't work for me (and there is no way to revert back "charge only").

Answer (score 1):

Look, I got tired of searching how to mount the drive automaticaly in UMS mode, and the solution above is right.

```
echo /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /sys/devices/lm-2/gadget/lun0/file
```

Search for the correct file `/sys/device` in your system.
 This way I can use Tasker to auto-mount my device whe a USB connection is detected.

Comment: "Above" has no context, since answers can be sorted in different ways. To which answer are you referring?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Android Forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/SF17BLxh174) the `sdutil` app on the phone can be used enable "USB Mass Storage" mode on the device.  This can be run through `adb` as:

```
adb shell sdutil ums enable
```

However, it seems like this only works on older version of Android (circa 2010?), on my device (which is not rooted), `sdutil` is not available (or is hidden somewhere I cannot see like `/sbin` or `/system/sbin`).